# $.html() returns undefined?

Tags: javascript, mustache

This line of code ($('#quiz-template').html();) always returns undefined despite the presence of a script element with the ID 'quiz-template'. I have no idea what the problem could be. Have any of you experienced such a thing? Any help would be appreciated.

index.html:

```
<script id="quiz-template" type="text/html">
  <h1>{{question}}</h1>
  <hr>
  <p class="right" style="display: none;">Richtig!</p>
  <p class="wrong" style="display: none;">{{explanation}}</p>
  <form id="answerForm" action="javascript:submitValue();">
    {{#possibleAnswers}}
    <div><label><input type="radio" name="answer" value="{{.}}">{{.}}</label></div>
    {{/possibleAnswers}}
    <input type="submit" value="Antwort bestätigen">
  </form>
</script>
```

app.js:

```
showPage = function(pageIndex) {
    currentPageIndex = pageIndex;
    if (currentPageIndex == 0) {
        template = $('#start-template').html();
        console.log($('#start-template').html())
        $('#content').html(Mustache.render(template));
    }
    else if (currentPageIndex == 11) {
        template = $('#end-template').html();
        $('#content').html(Mustache.render(template), tally);
    }
    else {
        template = $('#quiz-template').html(); // this returns undefined
        console.log($('#quiz-template').html());
        question = pickRandomQuestion();
        $('#content').html(Mustache.render(template, question));
    }
};
```

Comment: are you sure the script is executed after the element is loaded?

Comment: in your browser console can you try `$('#quiz-template').html()`

Comment: I did so when debugging, it returned undefined. But I don't know why

Comment: can you try `$('#quiz-template').length` in the console

Comment: okay, i'll have a try.

Comment: I tried it and it's 0

Comment: that means there is no element with id `quiz-template`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your showPage function executed on document load. Have you checked that?

EDIT:
I think the reason you could not get the html because of the "script" tag. I would recommend to use either of these:

```
1) Simple:
<textarea id="name" style="display:none">
        ... templates ...
</textarea>


2) Valid XHTML 1.1 (using CDATA):
<p style="display:none"><textarea id="name" rows="0" cols="0"><![CDATA[
        ... templates ...
]]></textarea></p>


3) Valid XHTML 1.1 (using comments; suggested):
<p style="display:none"><textarea id="name" rows="0" cols="0"><!--
        ... templates ...
--></textarea></p>
```